# python3 dynamoDB Update_item do not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I just practice using example code in AWS dynamoDB
But, update code do not work with error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update
```

My python code is here.
I could update DB without 'map' attribute.

```
table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')

title = "The Big New Movie"
year = 2015

response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        "year": year,
        "title": title
    },
    UpdateExpression="set #attrName.rating = :r, #attrName.plot=:p",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        "#attrName" : "info"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':r': decimal.Decimal(5.5),
        ':p': "Everything happens all at once."
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to update nested properties of top level property `info`, which does not exist yet (OR is not of [map type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html#DDB-Type-AttributeValue-M))

So before running this update you have to ensure that the top level attribute `info` already exists.

Or you can just catch the exception if it is thrown, and perform an another update creating the `info` attribute, like shown below:

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')

title = "The Big New Movie"
year = 2015

try:
    # Adding new nested attributes `rating` and `plot` 
    # if the top field `info` already exists and is a map
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            "year": year,
            "title": title
        },
        UpdateExpression="set #attrName.rating = :r, #attrName.plot=:p",
        ExpressionAttributeNames = {
            "#attrName" : "info"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': decimal.Decimal(5.5),
            ':p': "Everything happens all at once."
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )

except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ValidationException':
      # Creating new top level attribute `info` (with nested props) 
      # if the previous query failed
      response = table.update_item(
          Key={
              "year": year,
              "title": title
          },
          UpdateExpression="set #attrName = :attrValue",
          ExpressionAttributeNames = {
              "#attrName" : "info"
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues={
              ':attrValue': {
                  'rating': decimal.Decimal(5.5),
                  'plot': "Everything happens all at once."
              }
          },
          ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
      )
    else:
      raise
```